# conan does partial install of Boost on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, conan

I am encountering weird `conan` problems. My `conanfile.txt` reads:

```
[requires]
boost/1.71.0@conan/stable

[generators]
cmake
```

On running `conan install ..` from build directory i get the following message:

```
boost/1.71.0@conan/stable: WARN: Lib folder doesn't exist, can't collect libraries: /root/.conan/data/boost/1.71.0/conan/stable/package/f419497daccab81a781a793e5fffd7f228cf234e/lib
boost/1.71.0@conan/stable: LIBRARIES: []
boost/1.71.0@conan/stable: Package folder: /root/.conan/data/boost/1.71.0/conan/stable/package/f419497daccab81a781a793e5fffd7f228cf234e
```

`cd`ing into conan package install directory, there are no libraries (as warned by the message). The header files are incomplete with only 3-4 directories. Doing this multiple time yields the same result.What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Please add the version of Conan you're using and make sure that there is no similar bug report for that, let alone one that is fixed by a newer version.

Comment: Note that the latest boost recipes are available by using `boost/1.71.0` (without `@conan/stable`)

Comment: Do you have enough disk space? Have you tried [deleting the Conan cache](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/misc/remove.html)? Have you tried building boost (`conan install --build=boost`)